# Visual Studio Replace in Files Searches Skipped Matches After Each Replace

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

In VS Find and Replace > Replace in Files seems to repeatedly search skipped matches before finding new matches.

1. Perform a Find and Replace in multiple files: **File_1**, **File_2** and **File_3**
2. Skip one of the matches on **File_1** and proceed to the next file with Find Next
3. Make some replacements on the next file, **File_2**, using Replace
4. After the final replacement on **File_2**, the Find Next match goes back to previously searched files, **File_1** in this case, before going on to matches in **File_3**

I end up skipping through more and more previously searched files and skipped matches, just to find new matches. The Skip File option doesn't seem to help.

Is there a way to make Find/Replace search all un-searched files before looping back to the previously searched files?

I'm using VS 2012 but I seem to remember the same behavior in 2010.

**Update: this is a bug.** Please vote for a fix on [this Visual Studio UserVoice suggestion](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/6018384-fix-find-and-replace-replace-in-files-so-finds-a).

Answer (score 2):

I never noticed that.  You can do a Find in Files, Find All.  That way you have a list of all instances and can work your way down the list.  Double-click the first one, press Ctrl-H, and replace or skip all matches in that file.  Go back to your list and click the first match in the next file.

It will be harder to lose your place this way, but it is still tedious if you have a lot of files/matches to go through.

VS 2013 has the same behavior, in case you were curious.  Sorry I don't have a better answer.

Comment: Yes, and I often use Find All, but it has its own issues. If there are a large number of matches then you end up searching through the list of matches, accidentally skipping some, and double checking others.